# Which was the audience of "El Chavo" in the mid 70's?

Tags: audience-measurement

According to [El Chavo del Ocho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Chavo_del_Ocho)

> At its peak of popularity during the mid-1970s, it had a Latin
>   American audience of 350 million viewers per episode

But according to

[Latin America population in 1975](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=PV45XqbRH5q65OUPm7-7mAg&q=latin%20america%20population%20in%201975&oq=latin%20america%20population%20in%201975&gs_l=psy-ab.3...386.8467..8939...9.0..0.196.4415.20j21......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0j0i10j0i22i10i30j0i13j0i13i30j0i19j0i10i19j0i13i30i19j0i13i10i30i19j0i22i30i19j0i22i10i30i19j0i8i13i30i19j0i22i30j33i22i29i30.vcYPdf3X_RE&ved=0ahUKEwjm4_jx7bfnAhUaHbkGHZvfDoMQ4dUDCAY&uact=5)

The population of Latin America in 1975 was 322,7 millions. And I'm pretty sure in the mid 70's not everybody had a tv, as a matter of fact in the mid 80's my family in Latin America had a black and white tv.

Which was the audience of "El Chavo" in the mid 70's?

Comment: Per episode don't mean "per single airing". Also wiki entry is referencing Forbes which talk about "Latin Americas" while the entry itself write that series was poplar in Brazil and Spain. Which are not LA countries.

Comment: Spain isnt a latinamerican country, but Brazil is. Portugal is also a latin country, also France, Italy and Romania. Brazil is LatinAmerican because is in America and it has roots from a Latin country (Portugal)

Comment: It seems most likely the Forbes article is either wrong or mixed up some of the details.

Comment: @sanpaco I think so, but I've seen the same figure in several spanish websites. There is one which gives the same figure but refers to "spanish speaking countries". That could include Spain and Phillipines at the time which had spanish as official language, but it would remove Brazil so no gain

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that "most spanish speaking people with tvs" at the time watched "El Chavo". But how many were those I have no idea. I can't reach to that 350 millions figure for sure. If it would say over 100 millions I would believe it. Supposedly nowadays 45 years later and 50 years after its begining it has 91 million views per day

Comment: @Pablo My spanish is not the best but I also think that Forbes is talking about 350 millions per season in Latin America. Brazil is not a part of Latin America is North America.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY uhhh...... Brazil IS in South America and it's the largest country in both South America and Latin America (even though we don't have Spanish as official language, mostly due to the Portuguese colonization) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_America

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I didnt see that comment, I can't understand how you could think Brazil is part of North America. It's in South America, in the other corner. Besides there are only 3 countries in North America so they are well known

Comment: @Luciano You learn something new everyday. Back in my day in western eruope school Brazil was not Latin America because it was treated as separate "Luzoameryka" Lusitamerica. I wonder if it had something to do with Spanish and general Franco.